# Mark the android camera center

Tags: android, camera

I have written a simple camera app and I need to display the center of the camera to user (like default camera focus or very much pointing of sniper gun)

How can I achieve this. Please tel me.

Thank you!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FYP10Activity extends Activity {   
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with custom camera it needed serfaceview. I place a cross in the middle of relative layout. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with an intent call to the default camera, because you're handing control to another application during picture-taking. You'll have to override the Camera and add your own view on top of it. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html), under "Building a Camera App".

Answer (score 1):

By using Intent the control is switched from your activity to Camera Activity (Android Camera App), which has its own set of view elements. So you will have to write your own version of the app. A good demo code can be found [here](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html). Basically you have to setup a SurfaceView to render the preview frames and adjust its size to whatever you want.

Comment: Yes actually I knew that. But I wont to know how to draw/mark center ?